# get md5sum of all the version of a file in CVS

Tags: shell, cvs, md5sum

I have a CVS server which has around 50 version of a file. I want to get md5sum of all the versions. of course one way would be to revert to all version and get their md5sum but I am looking for a less painful method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming a GNU/Linux or similar environment, the following dump of a shell session illustrates a potential solution.  As CVS stores the files internally as `diffs` that must be processed to reconstruct the revisions, there really is no "less painful" method, but certainly some of the pain can be removed by using a script:

First, make sure the file has no local modifications:

```
$ FILE=FileToSum
$ cvs -nq update ${FILE}
```

Next, generate a list of all revisions of the file, iterate over them, checkout each revision, collect MD5 sums, then clear the sticky version from the work space to clean up.

```
$ cvs log -NS "${FILE}" \
> | awk '/^revision:/ { print $2 }' - \
> | while read revision; \
>   do \
>     echo -en "revision: ${revision}\n  "; \
>     cvs update -r ${revision} "${FILE}" >/dev/null 2>&1; \
>     md5sum "${FILE}"; \
>   done >md5sums; \
> cvs update -A ${FILE}
```

The output looks like this:

```
$ cat md5sums
revision: 1.17
  4e70589a177f688a3bf29a3843b840dd  FileToSum
revision: 1.16
  e9663f204cbc440235db7918e0be0a6a  FileToSum
revision: 1.15
.
.
.
```

Comment: Thanks, It worked, however, I had to replace '/^revision:/' with '/^revision/' . There is no ':' in cvs log in my setup.